# How to structure a comparison sentence?

Tags: word-order, comparative-constructions

What are the rules for using comparison with a verb and preposition?

Which of the sentences below is correct?

> (I need to) interact more with others using it

*Or*

> (I need to) interact with others more using it

Or something else?

Comment: It goes like a) more with others...(than with someone else); or more using it (than using something else...).

Answer (score 1):

*More* can indeed often go at different points in a sentence. But what it can't usually do is go inside a constituent of the sentence.

I take it that *with others using it* is a complement of *interact*: that complement is a constituent in the structure of the sentence, and cannot usually be split up by a word that is not part of it.

In fact, if I read your second sentence

> (I need to) interact with others more using it

I assume that the component *with others* is complete. It's fine for *more* to go on the end of that; but then I meet *using it*, and it's not obvious what its role is in the sentence. *Using it* is a participial phrase, but the only way I can make sense of it is to assume it relates to *I*, or possibly to the predicate *interact*. I can't read it as attached to *others* (which I assume was your intention).